# DatetimePicker changes the value of input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller, datetimepicker

I have a view that get a date from the user by `datetimepicker` as you can see here :

[image]

After clicking on the submit button the value is changed [image]

Note:the type of `DateOfLoanGet` is a datetime.

So why this problem is happened ?

Best regards.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. I think your datetimepicker's date format is `yyyy/MM/dd`. That's why it shows as `1393/07/20`. On the debug mode, you see your datetime value as `7/20/1393 12:00:00 AM` which has no implicit format.

Comment: So how can i change  the format of my datetime picker ?

Comment: You haven't even said what plugin your using. Perhaps check the doumentation

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the [formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATETIMEPICKERFORMAT%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true). Since it seems you want some custom format, I'd check [custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
dateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
```